# Discord.py rewrite - looking to see if a member is server muted, no info found on API Reference

Tags: python, discord, python-3.7, discord.py

How do I go about looking to see if a `Member` object is server muted? I can use the edit() function to mute them, but I want to retrieve a list of all members of a server that are muted. But I can't do that if I can't make a check to see if the `Member` object is muted.

Also how do I change a user's permission so they can't send messages (a mute function)

```py
if ctx.author.is_muted(): # <<< Goal :) Not a real function
    await ctx.author.edit(mute=False) # Is a real function, only works on voice connection.
else:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said (and as I know), there is no way to **mute** a server member properly using a function that is provided by the **discord.py API**. You can mute a member in the **voice chat** but not in **text channels**.

The only way to avoid a user to **send messages** is to create a *mute role* and change all the channels perms.

Here are some examples of what you can do to answer your question :

#### Mute role :

So we wan't to create a role called "muted" if it doesn't exist each time we call the command `mute @user` :

```py
import discord, asyncio
from discord.utils import get

async def create_mute_role(guild):
   '''
   `guild` : must be :class:`discord.Guild`
   '''
   role_name = "muted"
   mute_role = get(guild.roles, name = role_name)  # allows us to check if the role exists or not

   # if the role doesn't exist, we create it
   if mute_role is None:
      await guild.create_role(name = role_name)
      mute_role = get(guild.roles, name = role_name)  # retrieves the created role

   # set channels permissions
   for channel in guild.text_channels:
      await asyncio.sleep(0)

      mute_permissions = discord.PermissionsOverwrite()
      mute_permissions.send_messages = False

      await channel.set_permissions(mute_role, overwrite = mute_permissions)

   return(mute_role)
```

Your `mute @user` command will do something like :

```py
@commands.command()
async def mute(self, ctx, member: discord.Member):
   guild = ctx.message.guild
   mute_role = await create_mute_role(guild)
   await member.add_roles(mute_role)

   await ctx.send(f"{member.name} has been muted !")
   return
```

#### Get the muted members :

To get a list of your server muted members, you want to use [`role.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role.members).

So doing :

```py
muted_list = mute_role.members
print(len(muted_list))
```

Will display the amount of muted members, you can walk through this list with :

```py
for member in muted_list:
```

Hope it helped !

Comment: I was trying to avoid roles but this is ok.

Comment: As far as I know you cannot avoid role for this specific situation. I might be wrong, but I've never found another way to do this.